# OCI login FAILS using API with admin user

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the Python script given [here](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/python-script-to-report-all-compute-and-database-instances-1178) to get all resources for a user.
I was able to run it using the Tenancy user (which is not advisable) but not a test user created with admin permissions.
This admin user already has the permission for API keys generation.
But when I use the key in the config, it gives below error:

```
'target_service': 'identity', 'status': 404, 'code': 'NotAuthorizedOrNotFound'
```

Code where it fails (Line 177):

```
user = identity.get_user(config["user"]).data
```

Is there a Rule or Policy to be applied to the new user for enabling API access?

Update: I created another user in the DEFAULT domain and added it to default 'Administrators' group and it worked. But still not able to make it work using a test-domain admin user.

MY OCI INFRA:

Compartments(2) - ROOT, C2.

ROOT- domains(2) -> Default, test-domain.

C2- domains(1) -> Default.

Default- users(2) -> tenancyUser, defaultadmin

test-domain- users(1) -> testadmin

and other resources...

Comment: Hi, AhmadH. For helping you, we need more info. In which line is your failing code? Maybe the 176 (IdentityClient). Let me know and I will try to help.

Comment: And, I imagine you have generated the API keys for the new user and added to your config file https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apisigningkey.htm#two

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response.
Yes, I have created API key for the user and added in the config file.
It fails at get_user( ) call, as updated above.

Comment: More questions: 1) Have you changed your .oci/config to include the new user and/or created a new profile with this user? 2) Which is the content of config["user"] in the line 177 (this is read from .oci/config) 3) Which is the result of testing from [command line](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/3.37.13/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/iam/ui-password-information/get-user.html)

Comment: Additional: I have tested the code, and it worked for me with other user, but it's really old. I suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/oracle/oci-python-sdk/tree/master/examples/showoci)

Comment: Answers: 1) Yes, the config file is correct for testadmin user. 2) Its the user ocid for testadmin. 3) Never tested CLI as I need to use SDK.

Comment: I will try the latest code you suggested.

Comment: Hi @Sourcerer, the latest showoci example worked like charm. Now, I am able to run it with a normal user in a different domain with minimum read policy. I will deep dive into it to find out what is different here. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the script calls `oci.identity.IdentityClient.get_user(<user_ocid>)` which is ONLY for Default domain users.

Other domain users can call and use `oci.identity_domains.IdentityDomainsClient.get_user(<user_ocid>)` to get the user data.

Comment: Great! I did not realize you were using 2 domains. When I tested the problematic one, I was using default too.

Comment: @Sourcerer Thank you for taking out time to help me, really appreciated. :)